# Cloning Elements | For Each | Max Call Stack Exceed Error

Tags: jquery, clone, each

My objective is really simple. I have an array which has say 50 elements. Based on the length of the array, I would need to clone an existing DIV element in my HTML Doc. The Array has some data in it which I would like to use but I just cant seem to get beyond the max call stack error that I keep getting. Here is my code:

```
<div class = "SomeSuperParentElement">
    <div class = "someDiv" style = "display:none">
    </div>
</div>
    content = [length of this = 50];

    $.each(content, function(index) {
    $(".someDiv").clone().css("display", "").appendTo(".SomeSuperParentElement");
    });
```

Comment: What is `content`? show it

Comment: Its just an Array, to make things more descriptive, it has objects which have data that I would like to use once my 50 times cloning of the div element has been done.

Comment: [{name: "some String", lname : "something else"}, {name: "some String", lname : "something else"}, {name: "some String", lname : "something else"}, {name: "some String", lname : "something else"}, {name: "some String", lname : "something else"}, {name: "some String", lname : "something else"}]

Comment: So imagine that with a length of 50 indexes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove class `someDiv` on cloned elements, that causes error.

```
$.each(content, function(index) {
$(".someDiv").clone().removeClass('someDiv').css("display", "").appendTo(".SomeSuperParentElement");
});
```

Comment: @Minh Hat - not sure why I would need to remove class, I need them please..

Comment: @Minh Hat - I just took up your prescribed format, tweeked it by adding a ":first" to the append. Basically by the time I got your response, I kind of figured it out. But I just want to say thank you for responding, I am grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Binding the each array value to every div/element will cause a terrible performance problem. There's a better way to do this, that is binding a values on load event to the div/element

```
$('div').load(function(e){
       var elem = e.target;
       if (elem.nodeName==''){
           //.... your business goes here....
           // remember to replace $(this) with $(Elem)
       }
})
```

Read more you'll be interested in this article about event [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: Hello @rselvaganesh, so where do I place my cloning process, delegation ok but the cloning process is still not clear to me please on where to place it...